# find command written in bash script outputs command not found

Tags: bash, shell, find, command-substitution

```
#!/bin/bash
18 if [ "$arg" == "jpg" ] then
19      "$(find ./"$folder" -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec mv {} "$arg" \;)"
20 fi
```

This block of code above works and the find and mv command executes and I have the output in the jpg folder but my script outputs

> line 19: command not found.

The find command works fine without any such error outputs on the command line but when written in bash script prints `line number: command not found` only for the find command written above.

Comment: What are the outer quotes for?!? And why are you using the `$()` construction? Its used for getting output of a command as a string, not for running a command. IMHO both are to be removed.

Comment: Not a stellar duplicate, but just take out the superfluous command substitution around the command.